# How to get min and max from a timeseries data in SQL/Snowflake?

Tags: sql, time-series, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-timestamp

my data is something like this, timestamp is ordered in asc.

```
INSERT INTO timeseries (timestamp, value)
VALUES
  ('2022-01-01 00:00:00', 0.89),
  **('2022-01-01 10:01:00', 6.89),
  ('2022-01-02 10:01:21', 10.99),
  ('2022-01-02 10:07:00', 11.89),**
  ('2022-01-02 12:01:00', 0.89),
  **('2022-01-02 13:07:00', 6.39),**
  ('2022-01-02 14:00:00', 0.69),
  **('2022-01-03 14:02:00', 5.39),
  ('2022-01-03 15:04:00', 6.89),
  ('2022-01-03 15:00:00', 7.3),**
  ('2022-01-03 15:10:00', 1.89),
  ('2022-01-03 15:50:00', 0.8);
```

my ask is to get min and max, so i can produce difference in minutes whenever value is going above 5.
in above, there are three data sets formed

```
min  max 
2022-01-01 10:01:00  2022-01-02 10:07:00
2022-01-02 13:07:00  2022-01-02 13:07:00
2022-01-03 14:02:00  2022-01-03 15:00:00
```

I tried row_number to get sequence but since there are three sets there, i need to attribute column so i can use in partition clause but i am not getting any ideas for that?

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CASE WHEN VALUE>5 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END STATUS , TIMESTAMP, VALUE
FROM TIMESERIES)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STATUS ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) RN,TIMESTAMP,VALUE FROM CTE
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP;
```

this is giving me row_number for all >5 but I need based on sets of data..

any help to start or a solution is highly appreciated.

BDW, trying this in snowflake but general SQL is also fine.

Comment: Please read [How to create tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) and then show both sample data and expected result as tables. This makes your question much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard gaps and islands:

```
with flagged as (
    select *,
        case when
                lag(val, 1, 0.0) over (order by ts) <= 5
            and val > 5 then 1 end as flag
    from T
), grouped as (
    select *,
        count(flag) over (order by ts) as grp
    from flagged
)
select
    min(ts),
    max(case when val > 5 then ts end)
from grouped
group by grp
having max(val) > 5
order by grp;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/aGE2n6nk

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @shawnt00
query was not handling max values, so I had to write a lead in a separate case to get my desired output, I will share my query soon.

Thanks for your quick response though, Appreciated.!

Comment: I made a couple of incorrect adjustments after my initial post intending to catch scenarios where it should return any results. I've tested it this time.

Comment: wow, now I am getting desired results, 
your query is much more efficient than what I wrote, 
Thank you so much @shawnt00

Answer (score 1):

If we use the nice VALUES provided by shawnt00, in a CTE

```
with  T(ts, val) as (
    select * from values
      ('2022-01-01 00:00:00'::datetime, 0.89),
      ('2022-01-01 10:01:00'::datetime, 6.89),
      ('2022-01-02 10:01:21'::datetime, 10.99),
      ('2022-01-02 10:07:00'::datetime, 11.89),
      ('2022-01-02 12:01:00'::datetime, 0.89),
      ('2022-01-02 13:07:00'::datetime, 6.39),
      ('2022-01-02 14:00:00'::datetime, 0.69),
      ('2022-01-03 14:02:00'::datetime, 5.39),
      ('2022-01-03 15:04:00'::datetime, 6.89),
      ('2022-01-03 15:06:00'::datetime, 7.3),
      ('2022-01-03 15:10:00'::datetime, 1.89),
      ('2022-01-03 15:50:00'::datetime, 0.8)
)
```

we can then use [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event) to find when the conditional "greater than 5" swaps state:

```
select 
    ts, 
    val > 5 as gt_five,
    CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(gt_five) over(order by ts) as ct
from T
```

this gives:

| TS | GT_FIVE | CT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | FALSE | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 10:01:00.000 | TRUE | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 10:01:21.000 | TRUE | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 10:07:00.000 | TRUE | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 12:01:00.000 | FALSE | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 13:07:00.000 | TRUE | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 14:00:00.000 | FALSE | 4 |
| 2022-01-03 14:02:00.000 | TRUE | 5 |
| 2022-01-03 15:04:00.000 | TRUE | 5 |
| 2022-01-03 15:06:00.000 | TRUE | 5 |
| 2022-01-03 15:10:00.000 | FALSE | 6 |
| 2022-01-03 15:50:00.000 | FALSE | 6 |

we can use the `gt_five` to filter out the unwanted gaps with a QUALIFY, and then group via the output of the CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT to get the min/max. Thus the sql can be:

```
WITH flagged_and_stripped as (
    select 
        ts, 
        val > 5 as gt_five,
        CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(gt_five) over(order by ts) as ct
    from T
    QUALIFY gt_five
)
select
    min(ts) as min
    ,max(ts) as max
from flagged_and_stripped
group by ct
order by 1;
```

giving:

| MIN | MAX |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 10:01:00.000 | 2022-01-02 10:07:00.000 |
| 2022-01-02 13:07:00.000 | 2022-01-02 13:07:00.000 |
| 2022-01-03 14:02:00.000 | 2022-01-03 15:06:00.000 |

thus the complex example code is:

```
with  T(ts, val) as (
    select * from values
      ('2022-01-01 00:00:00'::datetime, 0.89),
      ('2022-01-01 10:01:00'::datetime, 6.89),
      ('2022-01-02 10:01:21'::datetime, 10.99),
      ('2022-01-02 10:07:00'::datetime, 11.89),
      ('2022-01-02 12:01:00'::datetime, 0.89),
      ('2022-01-02 13:07:00'::datetime, 6.39),
      ('2022-01-02 14:00:00'::datetime, 0.69),
      ('2022-01-03 14:02:00'::datetime, 5.39),
      ('2022-01-03 15:04:00'::datetime, 6.89),
      ('2022-01-03 15:06:00'::datetime, 7.3),
      ('2022-01-03 15:10:00'::datetime, 1.89),
      ('2022-01-03 15:50:00'::datetime, 0.8)
), flagged_and_stripped as (
    select 
        ts, 
        val > 5 as gt_five,
        CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(gt_five) over(order by ts) as ct
    from T
    QUALIFY gt_five
)
select
    min(ts) as min
    ,max(ts) as max
from flagged_and_stripped
group by ct
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution using Snowflakes semi-structured functionality (arrays):

```
with ranges as (
   select 
     case when lag(value,1,0.0) over (order by timestamp) < 5 and value >=5 then min(timestamp) end st_time,
     case when lead(value,1,0.0) over (order by timestamp) < 5 and value >=5 then max(timestamp) end end_time
   from timeseries
   group by value, timestamp),
ranges_arrays as (
   select 
     array_agg(st_time) st_time_arr,
     array_agg(end_time) end_time_arr,
     array_size(st_time_arr) row_count,
     array_generate_range( 0 , row_count ) idx_arr
   from  ranges)
select 
   st_time_arr[idx]::timestamp st_time, 
   end_time_arr[idx]::timestamp end_time 
from ranges_arrays, (select value::integer idx from ranges_arrays, lateral flatten(input=>idx_arr))
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @fieldy 
this has helped me to final my query.